# Is {∅} a subset of the power set of X, for every set X?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading the book "A Transition to Advanced Mathematics" 2014 edition, written by Smith, Eggen and St. Andre.

For every set X:

∅ ⊆  X

∅ ∈  power set of X

∅ ⊆  power set of X

{∅} ⊆  power set of X

Is {∅} ⊆ power set of X wrong?

I am an undergraduate student. Please help me!

**The definition of power set of X is the set whose elements are subsets of X.** (page 90 of the book)

I have this doubt because I remember that I read somewhere that ∅ ≠ {∅} because a set with the empty set is not empty.

Thanks for your answers!

What about this question:

**If the definition of power set of X is the set whose elements are subsets of X, and {∅} is not a subset of X. How {∅} can be a subset of the power set of X? Is not that an contradiction?**

Comment: Everything you wrote is correct.  What is your question?

Comment: @MJD: "Is {∅} ⊆ power set of X wrong?"

Comment: Note that if $A$ is a set, then $x \in A$ **iff** $\{x\} \subset A$.

Comment: The empty set is either ∅ or {}. Empty set = {∅} is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $A\subseteq B$ if whenever $a\in A$, then we have that $a\in B$ as well.

Since $\varnothing\in\mathcal P(X)$, it means that every element of $\{\varnothing\}$ is also an element of $\mathcal P(X)$, so $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ is indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your perspective ∅ = {∅}?

Comment: @Beginner: Absolutely not! $\varnothing$ is a set with **no** elements, while the set $\{\varnothing\}$ is a set with **one** element (namely, $\varnothing$).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If the definition of power set of X is the set whose elements are subsets of X, and {∅} is not a subset of X. How {∅} can be a subset of the power set of X? Is not that an contradiction?

Comment: @Beginner: No contradiction. $\varnothing$ is a subset of $X$, so $\varnothing$ is an element of $\wp(X)$, just as you said. And since $\varnothing$ is an **element** of $\wp(X)$, automatically $\{\varnothing\}$ is a **subset** of $\wp(X)$. This is no different from observing that $3\in\Bbb N$, so $\{3\}\subseteq\Bbb N$.

Comment: I think that I am starting to understand! Thanks!

Comment: @Beginner: $\mathcal P(X)$ has more elements than $X$, so it has more subsets as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe that I am understanding now. Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can we say $\phi$ is a subset of $2^A$? Here A is set.

Comment: @Kanwaljit: Why not?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am asking from you. Is $\phi$ subset and belongs to power set? And we need to write $\phi$ in curly brackets to show it as subset of power set?

Answer (score 1):

The empty set $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set $X$. Hence $\emptyset$ is a member of the power set of $X$, $P(X)$. Therefore $\{\emptyset\}$ is a subset of $P(X)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your perspective ∅ = {∅}?

Comment: No, that is false. See  comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this with an example.

Here's a set: $\{0,1\}$. Its power set ($\mathcal{P}$) is: $\{ \emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\} \}$. That's four elements. We can check that we calculated the power set correctly because we know that for a set $A$ with size $|A|$, the size of the power set is always $2^{|A|}$, and $2^2$ is $4$.

Here's another example: take the set $\{2,3,4\}$. It is clear that $\{2,3\}$ is a subset. And so $\{2\}$ is a subset as well.

With this example, we can see that $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ holds. Clearly $\{\emptyset,\{0\}\}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}$, so $\{\emptyset\}$ must be, too, even if may look unusual at a first glance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your perspective ∅ = {∅}?

Comment: @Beginner You're welcome, and no. Read it out to yourself: one of these is **the empty set**. The other is **the set containing the empty set**. These are different objects.

Comment: Note that $\emptyset$ is a set containing zero elements whereas $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set containing one element.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your help! I am clear now.

Answer (score 1):

One of those statements doesn't belong with the others. "∅ ⊆  power set of X" is correct, but irrelevant. I think that's what's confusing you.